# Lua iterate over letter-number pairs from string?

Tags: lua

I have a string that has a format like: "a3b12a5g625". First a letter and then a number. There can be any number of these pairs, from 1 to a whole lot.

I'm quite new to lua, and I'm trying to iterate over these pairs. How can this be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`string.gmatch`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-string.gmatch) with the [pattern](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#5.4.1): `%a+%d+`:

```
local str = "a3b12a5g625"
for pair in string.gmatch(str, "%a+%d+") do
    print(pair)
end
```

Output:

```
a3
b12
a5
g625
```

If you would like the numbers and letters split into separate variables, wrap each pattern item in a capture group:

```
local str = "a3b12a5g625"
for letters, numbers in string.gmatch(str, "(%a+)(%d+)") do
    print(letters, " ", numbers)
end
```

Output:

```
a       3
b       12
a       5
g       625
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want the pairs separate, then use

```
local str = "a3b12a5g625"
for a,b in string.gmatch(str, "(%a+)(%d+)") do
    print(a,b)
end
```